# NSAssert or NSLog in defaults switch case

Tags: objective-c, ios, assertions

I am wondering if I should use `NSLog(@"Switch out of range")` or `NSAssert(FALSE,@"Switch out of range");` in the following example:

```
typedef enum {
    kSectionFavoriteCarpark,
    kSectionPromotions,
    SectionsEnumCount
} SectionsEnum;


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case kSectionFavoriteCarpark:
            return self.locationFavoritesKeyArr.count;
        case kSectionPromotions:
            return self.promotionCarparks.count;
        default:
            DLog(@"index out of switch range");
            return 0;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (self.promotionCarparks.count > 0) {
        return SectionsEnumCount;//one for user defined positions one for favorite parkings
    }
    else {
        return SectionsEnumCount-1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assertions are for declaring facts that you *know* to be true, not for conditions that you *hope* to be true.  If this method is only ever called by your own code, then it makes sense to assert.  On the other hand, if this is a public method, an assertion would not be an appropriate way to perform what is essentially parameter validation.

Answer (score 4):

In writing Objective-C enums, it's much preferred to use the Objective-C macro `NS_ENUM`.  We also want our enum values to have a shared prefix, and one that will be reasonable unique to our project.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnumName) {
    MyEnumNameFavoriteCarPark,
    MyEnumNamePromotions,
    MyEnumNameCount
};
```

This makes it explicitly clear what the underlying type of our enumeration is, as well it puts our enum name right up top in the first line of the enum declaration.

It was always a good idea to name our actual enum values in this manner (using the enumeration name as the prefix to the value name).  It help us to know what values belong to the enum, helped with autocomplete, etc.  But it's particularly important to be in this habit now with the advent of Swift.

I know you're posting Objective-C code, and not Swift code, but that doesn't mean your Objective-C code won't ever be used in Swift.

I'm not sure how your enumeration, as written, would translate to Swift, but as I've written it, we can write a function that expects an argument of type `MyEnumName`, and instead of having to pass it `MyEnumNameFavoriteCarPark`, we can simply write `.FavoriteCarPark`.  We only need the part after the prefix.

And if we're not sure what value we need, we can always type the prefix part and let auto-complete come give us a list of available enumeration values--this is applicable in both Swift and Objective-C, if we write our enum correctly.